# Robot arm with steppers - speed

Tags: robotic-arm, joint

I am using a 5 axis Robot arm (Robolink robot from Igus) to perform some 3D printing routines. 
By now I am trying to use them and have him have some good position (and speed) control.
The robot is atuated by stepper motors (encoders included), but, generally, it lacks stiffnnes. When I tech him some consecutive reference positions its movement is not very soft.
I believe I can improve its behaviour by tunning speed references (maximum speed, minimum speed, reference speed) of each joint.
Can anybody give me some hint on how to set good speed references?

Comment: You can try micro-stepping and use a g code with the trajectory for the arm.

Answer (score 0):

I think the softness you describe has to do with stepper motor step sizes, try micro stepping to increase smoothness. And devise a motion profile with 3rd order spline to have acceleration equal to zero at turning points.